# How to build an Elastic Query with combination of criterias?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elatic search an unfortunately elasticearch.com documentation is not good enough. I know how to use term:

```
{
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
}
```

Would you please help to to build my query with these criterias?
(user = "ehsan" or user = "afsaneh") and ((age between 10 and 20) OR (age between 40 and 50))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at :

- `bool` query ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query)) : it will help you to combine the different criterias with AND/OR/NO using clauses `must`/`should`/`must_not`
- `range` filter ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html#query-dsl-range-filter)) : its goal is to exclude the documents that don't match the value interval you set.

The following query should do the trick :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user": "ehsan"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "user": "afsaneh"
              }
            }
          ]
        }        
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "age": {
                  "from": 10,
                  "to": 20
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "age": {
                  "from": 40,
                  "to": 50
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, imho, the Elasticsearch documentation is pretty good. 
You should take the time to read more in order to understand how to build other queries :like this (especially concerning the [difference between query and filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html#query-dsl-filters)).

Edit: the two `term` queries could be replaced by a single `terms` like this :

```
"terms": {
  "user": [
    "ehsan",
    "afsaneh"
  ]
}
```